# Как обратить остаток от деления?

Tags: c++, математика, mod

Если мы берем число `a` и берём остаток от деления на число `b` - получим число `c` ( `a % b = c` )
Есть ли способы обратить это дело, то есть имея `c` и `b` - найти `а`. Может используя какие-то доп. формулы?

Comment: При `b = 2, c = 0` `a` может быть любым чётным

Comment: for(int i = 1; true; ++i) { a = b * i + c; }  это еще не рассмотрены отрицательные числа

Answer (score 5):

Нет. И это математика, а не компьютерные технологии.

Благодаря тому, что это необратимая операция, существуют хэш-функции, загуглите, что это такое.

Такие операции как деление по модулю (взятие остатка) и взятие абсолютной величины (число без знака) осуществляются с сужением множества отображения.

Умножение на ноль, к примеру, теряет всю входную информацию. `x * 0 = 0` Найдите `x`? Неизвестно, что там было за число. Это любое число вообще,  потому что такая операция сужает множество отображения до единственного элемента, 0.

Answer (score 2):

Да, но найти целый ряд таких чисел.

Если

```
a = b*N + c
```

то

```
a%b == с
```

Весь вопрос только в том, какое именно `N` выбрать - годится любое.

> Может используя какие-то доп. формулы?

Если вым известно значение `a/b` - это урощает поиск конкретного значения.